# why variables in css is not working although I had read a lot about it?

Tags: css

I have variables in my css but it isn't recognized.I have tried setting variable like the code below but when I run it in chrome it doesn't work.

```
li {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

:special {
    background: yellow;
    --col: blue;
}

.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through lime;
    color: var(--col);
}
```

but when I set to blue directly it works like that

```
li {
    border: 2px solid red;
}

:special {
    background: yellow;
    --col: blue;
}

.completed {
    text-decoration: line-through lime;
    color: blue;
}
```

I don't understand what is the problem.

Comment: WTH is `:special`?

Comment: the problem is that we don't have any HTML code to answer you. In addition to the *strange* `:special` your are using, the HTML structure is also important to know how CSS variable will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:special` isn't a recognised selector which is most likely causing your problem here. People tend to add global custom CSS property declarations to the `:root {}` selector. Or simply scope them to the parent selector that you're using.

```
:root {
  --col: blue;
}

.class-name {
  color: var(--col);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`:special` is an **invalid selector**. Rules in invalid selectors are ignored as per the specification, so **your variable is never defined**.